# Statistical features of wavelet transform

Tags: matlab

Please could anyone explain what is meant by the following, and how I can find this using MATLAB? Any help would be appreciated.

> Statistical features of wavelet transform

Answer (score 0):

Statistical features can be any statistical value like mean, entropy, power, power over frequency band. This statement means *using a wavelet transform calculate statistical feature of signal*.

An example of it would be like generating a wavelet transform for transient detection. Now transient is a jump in signal it can be from custom statistical feature like change_in_amplitude/change_in_frequency.

Comment: can u please help me with the matlab for this

Comment: I did extensive signal processing in [IEEE Paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4237943/) and touched wavelet transforms a little. However, you can guide me to assist :)